# Get inserted document id in Meteor MongoObservable

Tags: mongodb, meteor, angular

So, i'm creating collection as suggested in angular2-meteor boilerplate:

```
export const BookCollection = new MongoObservable.Collection<Book>('books');
```

So, if i write something like this:

```
BookColletion.insert(..., callback_f);
```

I'm getting an error, that second parameter does not exists. So, how i supposed to get last inserted document's id?

Comment: where and how are you defining `callback_f`?

Comment: also, what is `MongoObservable`? did you perhaps want to use `Mongo.Collection` and then `BookCollection.find().observeChanges({..`?

Comment: `callback_f(err, docId){console.log(docId)}` works, but im not using that type of collection...

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what `MongoObservable` is, nor what that `<Book>` syntax means, but I suspect that what you want is something like this:

```js
export const BookCollection = new Mongo.Collection('books');
BookCollection.find().observe({
  added(document) {
    // document is the newly added document
  }
});
```

Comment: But when i do it in that way, in console.log(document) i have all documents, logged one by one. Here is a [pic](http://imgur.com/a/gheV8). I need latest, how i can achieve that?

Comment: This is a reactive block. As elements get added, the latest added will always be the latest shown. It shows up right after being added. Isn't that what you want? If you just want the last of all items (statically), then you'll need to sort them, but that doesn't require observers.

Comment: I need latest inserted _id for redirecting purposes.

Comment: Thank you. The `MongoObservable` returns, for each operations did on the collection (insert, add, etc.) an `Observable` instead of a `String`, `Cursor`, etc. And `<Book>` set the document model of the mongo collection.

Comment: Any solution yet?

Answer (score 2):

You can get the inserted id like this:

```
var insertedId = BookColletion.collection.insert();
```

as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41706273/use-id-from-collection-insert-within-a-meteor-method/41712441#41712441)