# How can I get id while inserting meteor/angular2

Tags: angularjs, meteor

I'm working on a project with meteor/angular and i want to get id while inserting an element to use it

my code ==>

```
collection.insert({
           name: name,
           birthDay: birthDay ,
           birthPlace:birthPlace,
           nationalities:nationalities,
           fields : fields
         });
```

I try this but it doesnt work

```
    const col = collection.insert({
               name: name,
               birthDay: birthDay ,
               birthPlace:birthPlace,
               nationalities:nationalities,
               fields : fields
             });
   console.log(col);
```

Comment: You should get the ID in the col variable as you tried. Can you provide more code?

Comment: Is your `collection` variable a Meteor-rxjs' [`MongoObservable.Collection`](https://angular-meteor.com/api/meteor-rxjs/latest/ObservableCollection#new_Collection_new), or a Meteor's [`Mongo.Collection`](http://docs.meteor.com/api/collections.html#Mongo-Collection)?

Comment: I'm using MongoObservable.Collection

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use id from collection insert within a meteor method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41706273/use-id-from-collection-insert-within-a-meteor-method)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess your `collection` variable is not a standard Meteor's [`Mongo.Collection`](http://docs.meteor.com/api/collections.html#Mongo-Collection), but a meteor-rxjs' [`MongoObservable.Collection`](https://angular-meteor.com/api/meteor-rxjs/latest/ObservableCollection#new_Collection_new), which `insert()` method returns an *Observable* instead of the newly inserted document's ID.

I.e. you have done something like:

```js
const meteorRxjsCollection = new MongoObservable.Collection('collectionName');
```

In that case, you have 2 easy solutions:

- Access the Meteor's Mongo Collection [behind](https://angular-meteor.com/api/meteor-rxjs/latest/ObservableCollection#Collection+collection) the meteor-rxjs wrapper:

```js
const newDocId = meteorRxjsCollection.collection.insert(newDoc);
```

- Subscribe to the Observable returned by meteor-rxjs [`insert`](https://angular-meteor.com/api/meteor-rxjs/latest/ObservableCollection#Collection+insert) method, to get the ID, in a similar manner as using a callback in Meteor's `insert`:

```js
const sub = meteorRxjsCollection.insert(newDoc).subscribe(function (newDocId) {
  sub.unsubscribe();
  // use newDocId…
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Database operations and method calls in Meteor are **by default** synchronous on the server and asynchronous on the client. That means that

```
collection.insert({ ... });
```

will return an id only when called on the server. If you want to have the inserted id in the client, you have to use a callback, since it's async:

```
collection.insert({ ... }, function (err, insertedId) {
    if (err) {
        throw err; // handle error your preferred way
    }
    // do something with insertedId
    console.log(insertedId);
});
```